# MacBook Pro и внешний SSD

Tags: macos, железо, ssd, macbook

Столкнулся с такой проблемой, для сборки проекто, не хватает диска на стареньком MacBook Pro 2015 года.

Задумался насчет внешнего накопителя, но не смог, пока что, найти информацию о том, как более правильно его подключить - хотелось бы что бы внешний жесткий диск работал как часть текущей файловой системы.

Возможно у кого то, есть ссылки или сталкивался с подобным как это провернуть ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Проще и надежнее** натурально взять и поменять имеющийся внутри ноутбука диск на SSD большего объема - так у вас не будет сложных схем с файловой системой.

При внешнем же подключении и объединении разделов, вы сильно рискуете потерять *вообще все* данные, если внешний диск по каким-то причинам отрубится.

Так что в случае со внешним диском, просто используйте пространство на нем, без объединения со внутренним диском.

Comment: Тоже так подумал - спасибо